# Can not vulcanize polymer project

Tags: polymer

I am trying to vulcanize my project. But my app is not wokring after vulcanizing. I doing via cmdline

```
vulcanize -s --inline --csp -v index.html
```

It looks like that my project is not vulcanized at all, according the fetches in network tool in chrome dev tools. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

I am using the app-router to navigate between my pages, but I think that this is not the problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: app-router is most likely the source of your problem.  Vulcanize does not know about app-router and its ability to load templates dynamically. 
I did not test it, but there is a chance that if you use the "pre-loaded" syntax and specify a polymer-element instead of a template html url, chances are it is going to work better (since you are going to be forced to import it using an import <link> that vulcanize understands.)

Answer (score 0):

Your command is contradicting itself, which is probably why it doesn't work

`--csp` Extract inline scripts to a separate file (uses .js)

`--inline` The opposite of CSP mode, inline all assets (script and css) into the document

Comment: IMHO "--inline --csp" is actually one of the most useful option. It takes  all inline and non inline and puts it all into a single external .js file.  (i.e. you should read this as being like two passes: first "--inline" external files, then "--csp" them all into a single file.